# Find $\mu$ given the area of the distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

A friend sent me this problem and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Let X be a normally distributed with mean, $\mu$, and standard deviation, $\sigma= \mu$. Also suppose $P(−2< X < 17)= 0.4375.$ $\hspace{0.4cm}$
Find the value of $\mu$.

Here's what I tried so far:
We know that $Z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. So, $P(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma} < Z <\frac{17-\mu}{\sigma}) = 0.4375$.

This tells us that $ P(\frac{17-\mu}{\sigma}) - P(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma} ) = 0.4375$.

How does the fact that $\sigma= \mu$ factor into solving the problem?

Comment: $\operatorname{erf}$ functions are involved.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& 0.4375 = \int_{-2}^{17}{1 \over \root{2\pi}\mu}
\exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{x - \mu}^{\, 2} \over 2\mu^{2}}}\dd x
\end{align}
$$
= 
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 2}\braces{%
\on{erf}\pars{17 - \mu \over \root{2}\mu} +
\on{erf}\pars{2 + \mu \over \root{2}\mu}}}}
$$

$\Large\mu \approx \color{#44f}{14.6004}$

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - it asks to find $\mu.$

Comment: With my answer you can find $\displaystyle \mu$. You can try it !!!.